# Migrations being applied according to User in models.py instead of being applied according to migrations in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have written a custom django migrations command as shown below

```
User = get_user_model()

def populate_asset_assignee(apps, schema_editor):
    for user in User.objects.all():
        user.save()
        # Some more code
```

The user model looks as follows

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    cohort = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    slack_handle = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey('SomeCentre',
                            blank=False,
                            null=True,
                            on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # Some more fields
```

I added the location field recently and have the migrations for it which is applied after this custom migration has been applied. The problem I am having is that whenever I try to make the migrations on the **test db** or a new database, I get the error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column core_user.location_id does not exist` which is being raised inside the `populate_asset_assignee` method when I try to do the `user in User.objects.all()`
Any ideas why `location_id` is beeing checked yet I haven't applied the migrations for the location field yet.

Comment: This is correct behavior. The model contains field `location` and `User.objects.all()` tries to populate `location` for each object. The correct solution depends on what exactly you are doing in the `populate_asset_assignee` function. You can start with [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#only) queryset method to avoid loading new fields, though in complex cases it might be better to rewrite queries to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for this. Let me test it out.